# Electron particle density

Tags: particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, astrophysics

I was solving an exercise in which I was asked to find the particle density for photons and electrons right after the big bang. I used the two following formulas:

$(\frac NV)_{BE}=g(\zeta(3)/\pi^2)(KT/\hbar c)^3$ where g is the degeneracy (2 for photons).

As for electrons (fermions):

$(\frac NV)_{FD}= \frac 3 4 (\frac NV)_{BE}$.

As expected I get the correct values in each case.

But then, there's this additional information :

The formula for calculating the electron particle density (fermion density) cannot be used nowadays, meaning 14 billion years after the big bang, and the reason given in my text is:

**A value for the number of electrons today cannot be determined with these formulas because they are not evenly distributed in phase space.**

Can someone explain to me what it is meant with the above sentence (in bolt)

Comment: I am not familiar with these calculations, but my naive guess is that they can no longer assume Maxwell-Boltzmann distributions?